# Why query set names, get slower after new pod starts

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod

Already running web app on kubernetes and facing issue, after new pod come with autoscale.
First touches on web are slower. I am already using shared caches&tmp for web. But when I look on database logs, there is issue:

```
2020-06-01T10:00:32.605088Z     3069191 Connect database@ip-of-node on database using TCP/IP

2020-06-01T10:00:32.673244Z     3069191 Query   SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'

2020-06-01T10:00:34.272685Z     3069193 Connect database@ip-of-node on database using TCP/IP
```

When I have only one pod, there is literally no time between first and second connect.
But when new pod come, there is "lag" when I try browse our web.
This "lag" is visible on database where time, between Query SET NAMES and second Connect ... TCP/IP,
take more time then normal. After enter something on web, 2nd time is running without "lag".

thanks for any advice

Comment: This is an interesting issue but I can't reproduce your environment with the info you provided, please reserve some time to read [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide all info relevant to your setup, like what Kubernetes version? Is it running on minikube/kubeadm/gke/eks/etc? what app and database are you working with? did you follow any guide? if so, post the link, if not, post the deployment and services yamls. This way you can get a faster and better answer and also enable others with similar issues to be helped as well.

Comment: I m following a lot of guides, but still same output. 
For now i add readinessProbe, into deploy yaml.
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
This help a lot, because now db communicate with nodes instantly and all the time.
But still don t know what happening inside.
Now i can see in db, every second nodes is connecting with database.
Connect database@ip-of-node on database using TCP/IP--
Query   SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'--
Connect database@ip-of-node on database using TCP/IP

Comment: I see, please add this information and the full yamls to the question, just press the `edit` button bellow your question. It would also be good to know if you are deploying it locally or in a cloud provider.